# How can I get the current Test with Split AB Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started a test with the Split AB Testing gem, which renders two different templates like

```
@test = ab_test("test", "template_1", "template_2")
```

At this point @test gives me the desired template name.
But I don't want to pass this parameter to the place I need it.

Is there a possibility to directly get the current test?

Comment: Where is this 'place I need it'? Could you elaborate about not wanting to  pass the needed parameter?

Comment: I would need to pass it through two controllers and several views, which is not handy and I think Split should provide this information directly.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the helper method

```
active_experiments()
```

provides all active experiments for the current user, which is exactly what I need. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Under the `Experiment Configuration` heading in the [documentation](https://github.com/splitrb/split), it says you can do something like this:

```
<% ab_test("my_first_experiment") do |alternative, meta| %>
  <%= alternative %>
  <small><%= meta['text'] %></small>
<% end %>
```

You could wrap that in an if admin or something so only you see it.